# qgis Semi automatic classification pluggin how to add text to rows in attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, remote-sensing, classification

I want to use a previously created shapefile as Training shapefile in the semi automatic cassification pluggin. Therefore i added 4 fields to this shapefile: Macro_ID (int), MCl_info (text), Class_ID (int), Class_info (text).
I could fill the int fields with the numbers but now i need to place the text into the others. It is exactly the same for all my 200something fields. I can not find a way to do it other than writing it manually. How can i automatically fill all fields of a row with the same text?